# Apostrophe issues with preg_match

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match, ascii, apostrophe

Hi first time question here ... I have the following pattern for preg_match that isn't working, which I have learnt may be an UTF-8 encoding issue ... or just my bad coding!

The following pattern works, but not for the apostrophe (with/without escaping the apostrophe makes no difference):

```
$pattern="/^([A-Za-z \'-])+$/";
```

The following pattern works for the apostrophe like I want it to, but it also allows the &, # and ; which is not ideal:

```
$pattern="/^([A-Za-z &#39;\-])+$/";
```

This pattern works properly for all characters, however only allows one instance of the apostrophe in the input text string (and I don't understand the significance of 0* in the &#0*39;):

```
$pattern="/^([A-Za-z \-])+(\'|&#0*39;)*([A-Za-z \-])+$/";
```

Can anyone shed light on where I'm going wrong? I have literally been through a hundred pages looking for an answer and it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$pattern="/^([A-Za-z \-]+(?:\'|&#0*39;)*)*[A-Za-z \-]+$/";
```

Comment: Awesome, that seems to be a solution that works! Thanks! Only change I'd make for the benefit of others viewing this is to delete the last \- just before the end, so words like "apple's" would pass, or "take-two" would pass, but "taketwo-" with the hyphen at the end would not. Nice work!!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried: "/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+/"

Comment: Thanks, yes I did try this. The apostrophe is just not recognised at all, it has to be the ASCII code unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if the input contains ' then replace the apostrophe to empty like this

```
$text = "Welcome I'm Lan Danel";
if (strpos($text, "'") !== false) {
        $input= str_replace("'","",$txtComment);
}
```

the output will be:

```
Welcome Im Lan Danel
```